# Trying to consume api using react-native

Tags: api, react-native

I created an api with laravel and now i want to be able to consume it using React-native but it's not working at all and I have no clue about it. Here are some code that i think can be helpful to help you try to help me.

That's my api.js file.

```
import {create} from 'apisauce';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
const api = create({
    baseURL:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
});

api.addAsyncRequestTransform( request => async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@PetFinder:token');

    if(token) {
        request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    request.headers['Content-Type']  = `application/json`; 
    request.headers['accept']        =  `application/json`
});
```

And here is my Login page

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

import api from '../../services/api'

export default function Login() {

  async function handleSubmit()
  {
    const response = await api.post('/login', {
      email: 'nowahmst@gmail.com',
      password:'123456',
    });
  }

  return (
    <View><Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Login" > </Button></View>
  );
}
```

[image: Error Message]

Back-End is running, I'm able to get the response using postman or insomnia and my route is set to be post as well the api request.

Comment: looks like there is an error that is unhandled, if you wrap your `handleSubmit` function in a `try catch` statement you should be able to log the error

Comment: also there is a key `problem` that indicates the server was unreachable, perhaps you have the wrong address or port

Comment: the address and port are correct .The console.error(e.message) returned undefined